# Could not find module for target 'x86_64-apple-ios-simulator' when building for simulator

Tags: swift

I receive this error Could not find module for target 'x86_64-apple-ios-simulator' when I build my app for simulator only. I tried with multiple simulators and it repeats.

Everything is ok, when I build for real iphone connected to my computer. It also works fine if I build for archive.

I have Xcode: Version 14.2 and Macbook on M1 with MacOs 13.2.1, my app is in Swift.

I have some pods for firebase and openai.

I have read many answers regarding this error message, but as far as I understand there are many solutions for many problems related to this message.

I have tried setting Build Active Architecture Only both Yes and No. I have tried overriding in Podfile as well. I have tried adding x86 to list of Architectures.

None of those solutions worked for me.

Comment: One of the pods likely doesn't have `x86_64-apple-ios-simulator` capabilities. try switching to SPM packages seem more versatile.